# How to split "['string1']['string2']['string3']"

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string "['string1']['string2']['string3']".
Expected result will be following list
['string1', 'string2', 'string3']

```py
mystr = "['string1']['string2']['string3']"
subl = mystr.split("['")
print(subl)
key_path = []
for i in subl:
    if i:
        key_path.append(i.strip("']"))

print(key_path)
```

But I want a regular expression or built in function that will perform all above steps and return the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

I like using a regex based approach here because it is clean.  Using `re.findall`:

```
inp = "['string1']['string2']['string3']"
parts = re.findall(r'\[\'(.*?)\'\]', inp)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

Comment: This is also working with nested "[ ]" 

    inp = "['string1']['string2']['string3 [0x91]']"
    parts = re.findall(r'\[\'(.*?)\'\]', inp)
    print(parts)

This prints:

    ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']